# ITest .getTestName() returns null if test is skipped (because of dependsOnGroups)

Tags: java, testng

**What I want to do**

I'm trying to generate a custom test report, which displays a custom test name. I do this by implementing "the ITest strategy" where you override the `getTestName()` method to provide your own.

In my report, I have the method name (from `.getMethodName()`, for example `testIfStatusCodeIs200`) and the test name (from `.getTestName()`, which I customise, and returns for example `Tested endpoint is: http://cakeAPI/api/cakes/cakeId`).

**How the code looks like**

```
public class BaseTest implements ITest {

    private String uri = null;

    public BaseTest(String uri) {
       this.uri = uri;
    }


    @Test (groups = { "myGroup" })
    public void test1() {
        // do something
    }


    @Test (dependsOnGroups = { "myGroup"})
    public void test2() {
         // do something
    }

    public String getTestName() {
        return uri;
    }
}
```

This is the report generator logic. This is a pretty big function and most of it consists in appending and writing to an HTML file, so I voluntarily cut out pieces that I believe are non important for the problem:

```
public class CustomTestNGReporter implements IReporter {

    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {

        try {

            // Create test methods summary data.
            String customTestMethodSummary = this.getTestMehodSummary(suites);

            //... Append results to html

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /* Get test method summary info. */
    private String getTestMehodSummary(List<ISuite> suites) {

        try {
            for (ISuite tempSuite : suites) {
                Map<String, ISuiteResult> testResults = tempSuite.getResults();

                    for (ISuiteResult result : testResults.values()) {
                        ITestContext testObj = result.getTestContext();

                        /* Get failed test method related data. */
                        IResultMap testFailedResult = testObj.getFailedTests();
                        String failedTestMethodInfo = this.getTestMethodReport(testFailedResult);

                        /* Get skipped test method related data. */
                        IResultMap testSkippedResult = testObj.getSkippedTests();
                        String skippedTestMethodInfo = this.getTestMethodReport(testSkippedResult);

                        /* Get passed test method related data. */
                        IResultMap testPassedResult = testObj.getPassedTests();
                        String passedTestMethodInfo = this.getTestMethodReport(testPassedResult);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* Get failed, passed or skipped test methods report. */
    private String getTestMethodReport(IResultMap testResultMap) {

        Set<ITestResult> testResultSet = testResultMap.getAllResults();

        for (ITestResult testResult : testResultSet) {

            String testURI = testResult.getTestName();
            System.out.println(testURI); // null for skipped tests
        }

        return null; 
    }
```

**What is the problem**

The problem is that if `test1()` fails, then `test2()` is skipped, and it seems that in this case `getTestName()` for `test2` returns `null`.

For example, if the test of `testIfStatusCodeIs200` fails, then I will skip `testIfResponseHas10Elements`. The test name associated with `testIfStatusCodeIs200` will return the custom test name, while the test name of `testIfResponseHas10Elements` will return `null`.

Is there a way to 'force' `getTestName()` to be evaluated even though the test has been skipped ?

Comment: Maybe I'm just blind, but I cant see the relation between `ITest` and `ITestResult`. Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Updated the report code to provide more clarity on where ITestResult comes from. Does that help ? Still, the relationship between ITest and ITestResult is also unclear to me.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/8d1c11bc267ea52157e20ebf6781d1ca9fe7ed1c/src/main/java/org/testng/ITestResult.java about `ITestResult.getTestName()` : "If this result's related instance implements ITest or use @Test(testName=...), returns its test name, otherwise returns null."

Comment: Did you try `testResult.getMethod().getMethodName(); ` ?

Comment: Yes, I do use `.getMethodName()`, to retrieve the method name. However, as far as I know `.getMethodName()` can not be 'overriden', in the sense that it will get me back the actual method name, and I cannot customise it. In my report, I have the method name (from `.getMethodName()`, for example `testIfStatusCodeIs200`) and the test name (from `.getTestName()`, for example `http://cakeAPI/api/cakes/cakeId`). The test name is customised to return the endpoint url that is being tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make use of the latest released version of TestNG (6.14.3) you will not see any null values. You will instead at-least get the actual `@Test` annotated method name.

I have filed a bug for ensuring that if there's an `ITest` implementation available in the test class, then TestNG should always retrieve that even for skipped methods as well.

You can track the issue here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1756

The fix should be available in the upcoming version of TestNG viz., **7.0.0**

You can add yourself as a watcher to the above mentioned issue to track it.